# Declare Property in C#

Tags: c#, properties, public

When We should use :

```
public string User { get; set; }
```

And When :

```
private string _user;
public string User
{
     get { return _user; }
     set { _user = value; }
}
```

And When:

```
public string User;
```

For example I have `Class` that containts `user` property.
How should I decide that which one of the choices that I wrote I should  use ?

Comment: You first example is invalid.

Comment: I edit it, it was just writing mistake. Now it is valid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general rule of thumb, you should only really use a property with a backing field when you need to do something else in the getter or the setter - validating some input, changing additional state, or raising a property changed notification, for example:

```
private string _user;
public string User
{
    get { return _user; }
    set
    {
        _user = value;
        this.RaisePropertyChanged(x => x.User);
    }
}
```

Otherwise, you can just use an auto-property:

```
public string User { get; set; }
```

You don't need a backing `_user` field for this.

Personally, I would avoid having public variables on classes.

Comment: "You don't need a backing _user field for this." - - > it is only writting mistake.
And I didn't understant this row :` this.RaisePropertyChanged(x => x.User);`

Comment: Good, I thought so. Don't worry too much about the `RaisePropertyChanged` line, it's just an example of some code that could (and often does) appear in a setter. It raises a `PropertyChanged` event that XAML bindings listen for, it's important in the MVVM pattern.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a general rule, if you're in a team, it might depend on your team's agreed conventions. As a rule of thumb, using setters and getters allows you to have more control over what you can do with a property, like validating the input, formatting the output, raising an event, deciding that a property can be set / read only privately, etc.

Answer (score 1):

1st (autoproperty) is basically the short form of doing the 2nd.
As for the usage it is helpful in validating input, raising events, etc, eg

```
private string _user;
public string User
{
    get { return _user; }
    set
    { 
        if(!(value == ""))
            _user = value; 
    }
}
```

In any case it is advisable to use getters and setters.